# how to get wrapped lines from multiline textbox?

Tags: c#, textbox, multiline, word-wrap

In my windows.forms c# application, I have a multi-line textbox with WordWrap = true. After I set Text property to a long string, I need to get all lines produced by wrapping. It is not the same as Lines[] property, because my text does not include new line characters.
I have found solutions using graphics MeasureString function but it seems a little bit extra work considering that the textbox control already did the wrapping - why should I do the same work again?
Is there any way to get the lines into which the textbox wraps the text?

Thank you

Comment: Just assuming, but I think measuring the string might just be the simplest way :/ ... Especially if you already have solutions for it.

Comment: The purpose of the TextBox is to display text and allow text input but not to process text. TextBox cannot give you the requested information..

Comment: Olivier: but I don't want process the text. I want to know exactly how the box displays the text, i.e. what is the first line, what is the second line etc.

Answer (score 7):

Can you check the below solution,

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textBox1.Text = "This is my text where I want to check how I can get wrapped content as seperate lines automatically !! This is my text which I want to check how I can get wrapped content as seperate lines automatically !!";
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool continueProcess = true;
    int i = 1; //Zero Based So Start from 1
    int j = 0;
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();
    while (continueProcess)
    {
        var index = textBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i);
        if (index != -1)
        {
            lines.Add(textBox1.Text.Substring(j, index - j));
            j = index;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            lines.Add(textBox1.Text.Substring(j, textBox1.Text.Length - j));
            continueProcess = false;
        }
    }
    foreach(var item in lines)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(item);
    }
}
```

[GetFirstCharIndexFromLine Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.getfirstcharindexfromline(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Line numbering in the text box starts at zero. If the lineNumber
>   parameter is greater than the last line in the text box,
>   GetFirstCharIndexFromLine returns -1.
>
> *GetFirstCharIndexFromLine returns the first character index of a
>   physical line. The physical line is the displayed line, not the
>   assigned line. The number of displayed lines can be greater than the
>   number of assigned lines due to word wrap. For example, if you assign
>   two long lines to a RichTextBox control and set Multiline and WordWrap
>   to true, the two long assigned lines result in four physical (or
>   displayed lines).*

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Perfect!! Way better than using API calls or measuring widths. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A little pinvoking would work:

```
private const UInt32 EM_GETLINECOUNT = 0xba;

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  int numLines = SendMessage(textBox1.Handle,
                             EM_GETLINECOUNT, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero).ToInt32()
  MessageBox.Show(numLines.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### REVISED ANSWER

I checked the Win32 APIs again and realized it could be done easily. I wrote an extension method so you can do it even easier:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class TextBoxExtensions
    {
        private const uint EM_FMTLINES = 0x00C8;
        private const uint WM_GETTEXT = 0x000D;
        private const uint WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = 0x000E;

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, StringBuilder lParam);

        public static string[] GetWrappedLines(this TextBox textBox)
        {
            var handle = textBox.Handle;
            SendMessage(handle, EM_FMTLINES, 1, IntPtr.Zero);

            var size = SendMessage(handle, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero).ToInt32();

            if (size > 0)
            {
                var builder = new StringBuilder(size + 1);
                SendMessage(handle, WM_GETTEXT, builder.Capacity, builder);
                return builder.ToString().Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            }

            return new string[0];
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
var lines = textBox1.GetWrappedLines();
```

### ORIGINAL ANSWER

> WinForm TextBox is actually a wrapper of Windows GDI edit control, which handles text  wrapping natively. That being said, even if the TextBox keeps an array of wrapped lines, it is not exposed by public API, not even brought to managed environment (which, if it did, can however be retrieved with reflection). So your best bet is still MeasureString.

Comment: Got it, thank you. Is there any chance to get exact number of lines at least?

Comment: I looked into edit control docs again, I might be wrong about it. Actually you should be able to send a EM_FMTLINES

message to the edit control, followed by a WM_GETTEXT message to retrieve the wrapped text. I'll do some experiments and revise my answer when I have time.

Comment: Hi, please check out my revised answer

Comment: Thank you hillin, I tested it, and it works perfectly! I am going to use it for my project.

Comment: I only made one correction: for my purposes, I need empty lines too, so I replaced your "return builder" line with this:

Comment: According to MSDN, wrapped lines are delimited with \r\r\n, so just split the string like that.

Comment: return builder.ToString().Split(new[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);          As you can see, I use "\r\n" instead of separate chars, because they give too many empty lines. Now, the function returns exactly those lines that are displayed by the multiline textbox, even when you entered few empty lines by pressing ENTER key. Thanks again.

Comment: @hillin Can this approach also work with RichTextBox instead of TextBox. It worked fine for TextBox but it didn't work for RichTextBox. Is there any other API available for RichTextBox or do I have to use different Control Messages?

Comment: @torno I believe it's doable, although significantly more complex. Read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/use-word-and-line-break-information

Answer (score 0):

```
    To check if particular line is wrapped or not, here is the GDI Function you need to use:
    1. [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int DrawText(IntPtr hdc, string lpStr, int nCount, ref Dimension lpRect, int wFormat);

    Here are what you need to get things done:
      public enum DrawTextFlags
        {
            CalculateArea = 0x00000400,
            WordBreak = 0x00000010,
            TextBoxControl = 0x00002000,
            Top = 0x00000000,
            Left = 0x00000000,
            HorizontalCenter = 0x00000001,
            Right = 0x00000002,
            VerticalCenter = 0x00000004,
            Bottom = 0x00000008,
            SingleLine = 0x00000020,
            ExpandTabs = 0x00000040,
            TabStop = 0x00000080,
            NoClipping = 0x00000100,
            ExternalLeading = 0x00000200,
            NoPrefix = 0x00000800,
            Internal = 0x00001000,
            PathEllipsis = 0x00004000,
            EndEllipsis = 0x00008000,
            WordEllipsis = 0x00040000,
            ModifyString = 0x00010000,
            RightToLeft = 0x00020000,
            NoFullWidthCharacterBreak = 0x00080000,
            HidePrefix = 0x00100000,
            PrefixOnly = 0x00200000,
            NoPadding = 0x10000000,
        }
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct Dimension
        {
            public int Left, Top, Right, Bottom;

            public Dimension(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
            {
                this.Left = left;
                this.Right = right;
                this.Top = top;
                this.Bottom = bottom;
            }
            public Dimension(Rectangle r)
            {
                this.Left = r.Left;
                this.Top = r.Top;
                this.Bottom = r.Bottom;
                this.Right = r.Right;
            }
            public static implicit operator Rectangle(Dimension rc)
            {
                return Rectangle.FromLTRB(rc.Left, rc.Top, rc.Right, rc.Bottom);
            }
            public static implicit operator Dimension(Rectangle rc)
            {
                return new Dimension(rc);
            }

            public static Dimension Default
            {
                get { return new Dimension(0, 0, 1, 1); }
            }
        }

So to know whether a particular line is wrapped or not, you would call the function like this:
Dimension rc = new Dimension(0,0,2,2);
var flag =  DrawTextFlags.CalculateArea | DrawTextFlags.TextBoxControl | DrawTextFlags.WordBreak;
DrawText(hdc, line, line.length, ref rc, (int)flag);
Now if height of rc you get after executing this function is greater then your font height or tmHeight if you use TextMetric (that is what minimum required for a line to fit vertically) you can safely assume your line is wrapped.
Apart from this,
You can use the following function as an alternative approach:
static extern bool GetTextExtentExPoint(IntPtr hDc, string str, int nLength,
            int nMaxExtent, int[] lpnFit, int[] alpDx, ref Size size);
```